# Installed IIS but get blank page and it doesn't show up in Windows services list

Tags: iis

I am trying to install IIS on my Windows 8.1 laptop and followed the directions at Microsoft for installing IIS. But when I type localhost, instead of getting the IIS start page, I get a blank page.

When I do Windows + R and type services.msc, the resulting list of services is long but does not include Internet Information Services.

When I look at the Windows filesystem, I do find the inetpub folder with four subfolders, including wwwroot. In the wwwroot folder is the iisstart.htm file that is supposed to display when I type localhost into my browser.

I have read that one possible problem is that both Skype and IIS want to use Port 80 and there is a conflict. So I decided to try to change the default port for IIS, but I found that I don't appear to have the IIS Manager on my system. When I go to Administrative Tools, Internet Information Services Manager is not on the list of administrative tools.

I added both the HTTP Redirection module as well as the IIS Management Service on top of the initial basic installation that Microsoft described. Still no luck getting IIS working or IIS Manager to appear.

I have tried to research this problem of getting IIS to work on Windows 8.1 with no success and am at a loss. Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 117):

In Control Panel --> Programs --> Programs And Features --> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content.

Also make sure .NET Extensibility 3.5 and .NET Extensibility 4.5 are checked.

Comment: Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content

Comment: Ironically I tried to only install the parts I needed to save time but then spent more time trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: I was building 10 servers from scratch and only had to do this on one - go figure. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 17):

Major fail by Microsoft. Why the hell would they turn off the most basic features by default. Go to Turn Windows features on or off (just search "features"). Look in IIS, WWW, Common HTTP Features. See attached image.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgf3W.png)

Answer (score 9):

I have solved a couple of my problems.

I installed several more IIS modules: Static Content, IIS Management Console, and HTTP Errors.

I am now am able to find the IIS Manager in the Administrative Tools list and can use the IIS Manager.

Also, when I pressed Windows key + R and typed in services.msc, I still don't see Internet Information Services in the list. However, I do see "World Wide Web Publishing Service" in the list and it is shown as running. A page at Microsoft's Technet site indicates that it is related to IIS.

The HTTP Errors module gave me an error page rather than a blank page when I typed in localhost and also when I typed localhost/filename. This proved a HUGE help, because the error page identified the problem as a permissions issue. I thought I had dealt with the permissions issues, but this error page made it apparent that I had not.

When I typed in localhost, I got the permissions error. When I typed in localhost/iisstart.htm, I got the proper display of the file. When I created a simple .htm file, statictest.htm, and placed it in the wwwroot folder along with iisstart.htm, and typed localhost/statictest.htm, I got the permissions error.

So since one of the files was working and one wasn't, I decided to compare their permissions. (You do this using the File Explorer. Right click on the file, click on Properties, click on Security Tab. To make changes, click on Edit.) I saw that the successful one had a user listed that the unsuccessful one did not. So I added a user for the statictest.htm file to the permissions list with full control. That solved the issue for that file and it displayed normally.

I now am back to getting a blank page when I type in localhost. It must not be a permissions issue, because otherwise I'd get the permissions error page. I'm not sure what the cause of the blank page is. But as long as I can get files to display when I give their name, I am happy enough.

I am happy to report that my PHP installation is also working, at least as judged by the fact that the phpinfo() function displays properly.

So to sum up: if you are having problems getting IIS to work on Windows 8.1, try adding more IIS modules and make sure your permissions are in order. I think the most important ones to add are Static Content and HTTP Errors. Also, of course, CGI if you are going to use PHP.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older post, but in case anyone, like me, already had "static content" enabled, there was one other thing that needed to be done to resolve this issue.

Under "Programs and Features" -> "Turn Windows features on or off"

Expand "Internet Information Services" -> "World Wide Web Services" -> "Application Development Features"

Make sure that "ASP.NET 4.5" (and if needed/installed 3.5) are selected.  This should automatically check ".Net Extensibility" for the selected version, and it should also enable ISAPI filters and Extensions.

By default (for me at least) these options were not turned on when I enabled IIS.  I was getting a 500 error in IE if I had "Show Friendly Error Messages" turned on in IE, but if I turned that option off, I would get a completely blank page.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reason was that I had two different HTTP handlers in the config with the same name. I didn't get any errors, just blank response.

I'm guessing that some other parts of the configuration may result in a similar behavior. **Try commenting out some parts of Web.config file** in case you cannot figure the problem out.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.
Win 10 upgraded from 7. Default documents server blank and without error.
Static Content and Default Document features already enabled.
I resolved by disabling both features, rebooted and tried(received error 404), enabled both features, rebooted, pages served properly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using Windows Server 2008 on an Azure machine, it was missing some packages which can be installed using "Web Platform Installer", and then search for "recommended server configuration for web hosting providers"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the blank page problem as well on IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.
I had StaticContent installed as Windows feature.

What finally fixed it for me was changing the Path Type of the StaticFile Handler under [IIS Manager -> Server on left pane -> Handler Mappings -> StaticFile] from "Unspecified" to "File or Folder".
You can also change this on a per web site basis instead of the entire server (but I don't really see a reason why to do so, as it breaks pretty much any page). Make sure, however, that the site does not have an overriding setting for the StaticFile handler, as the site scoped one is preferred over the global one.